# How to refer to image of homset under a (not full, not faithful) functor.

Tags: category-theory, functors, hom-functor

Consider a functor $F: C \rightarrow Set$. If $F$ is not full and not faithful, how can I talk about the image of $F$ on morphisms (a subset of $Hom_{Set}(F(c), F(c'))$) in relation to $Hom_C(c, c')$? Using a mix of set-theoretic and category theoretic terms, I might describe this subset of $Hom_{Set}(F(c), F(c'))$ as $Hom(c, c') / \sim$ where two morphisms in $Hom_C(c, c')$ are equivalent if their images are the same under $F$. I'd like to describe this kind of equivalence relation using a category theoretic construction.

Comment: I changed the title to something more self-explanatory. If you feel that doesn't reflect what you want, please feel free to rollback.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz That seems fine. I had avoided this clearer title because I didn't have the "under a functor" phrase in my vocabulary until now. Thanks!

Comment: There is no established name for that subset. When you use it in a paper or writeup of any kind, just say what it is.

Comment: The question "I'd like to describe this kind of equivalence relation using a category theoretic construction." is not focused. There is no answer for that type of general question.